# Can I add 'ON DELETE CASCADE' to tables managed by Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have some tables managed by Hibernate with various foreign key constraints. Cascade on delete is currently managed by Hibernate alone. For playing around with test data I often create and remove some rows by hand. It would help me a lot if I could add ON DELETE CASCADE to the foreign key constraints but I don't know if Hibernate trips over this because the database removes stuff before Hibernate does.

---

A lot of people seem to concentrate on DDL. My intention is **not** to instruct Hibernate to create DDL with SQL DELETE CASCADES. I just want to know if it does any harm if I specify an ON DELETE CASCADE in the database **in addition** to having JPA's `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` on the reference annotation, e.g., `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: I think the answer above only covers Hibernate managed Cascade however I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502481/on-cascade-delete-on-jpa2-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: The answer is about DDL creation which is not important to me. I want to know whether CASCADE at the DB level is OK for Hibernate. The fact that there is an `@OnDelete` annotation _may_ be proof that it is.

Comment: Well that was just a starting point. I'm not sure agree it's just about DDL. Some further research may have led you to some comments here by Gavin King hiself: http://www.mail-archive.com/hibernate-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03803.html

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286649/jpa-hibernate-cascade-delete-in-both-database-and-annotation

Answer (score 6):

You can use `CascadeType.DELETE`, however this annotation only applies to the objects in the `EntityManager`, not the database. You want to be sure that `ON DELETE CASCADE` is added to the database constraint. To verify, you can configure JPA to generate a ddl file. Take a look at the `ddl` file, you'll notice that `ON DELETE CASCADE` is not part of the constraint. Add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to actual SQL in the `ddl` file, then update your database schema from the ddl. This will fix your problem .

This [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) shows how to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on for `CONSTRAINT` in MySQL. You do this on the constraint. You can also do it in a `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statement. It's likely that JPA creates the constraint in an `ALTER TABLE` statement. Simply add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to that statement.

Note that some JPA implementors do provide a means for this functionality.

Hibernate does supply this functionality using the `@OnDelete` annotation, thus it is preferred to use this or simply update the ddl file if you would like to stick with standard JPA functionality.

Answer (score 5):

You can safely use `ON DELETE CASCADE` as long as you do not have `CascadeType.REMOVE` or `orphanRemoval` enabled to prevent propagation of the entity removal event.

Having `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` on your relation will force Hibernate to generate `ON DELETE CASCADE` for related foreign keys. However your `Dialect` has to indicate that such relation are supported by returning `true` in `supportsCascadeDelete` method.

[Dialect.supportsCascadeDelete()](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.java#L2346)

[OnDelete](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/OnDelete.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would have expected Hibernate to take care of the dialect's support and do the right thing either way. Apparently one needs to be aware of that. One more reason I'm glad to have left ORMs behind me... I hope I never have to deal with them again.

Answer (score 3):

I see two potential issues:

1. If an entity that represents the table to which you cascade operations directly in the database is versioned, then it would not work because when Hibernate tries to delete records on its own, the version check would fail (Hibernate would assume concurrent thread already updated or deleted the corresponding records).
2. If there are use cases in which your business logic re-persists such entity instances after removal has been cascaded to them from the parent (for example, you are deleting old parent and migrating associated children to a new one, although for better clarity I would not cascade removal at all if such a use case exists for an association, but it's up to you as it is allowed by the JPA spec), then Hibernate would just [un-schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840903/silently-ignored-remove) the deletion of children and delete only the parent, so you would still end up with deleted children if you cascade deletion in the database.

Probably there are some other situations that could be problematic in some scenarios, so I would recommend **not** to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native database functionality to delete the child records upon deletion of parent record.

Be aware of bi-directional relationships and to be sure, ensure you just specify insert and update in cascade (to be on safer side).

Answer (score 1):

You mention for testing purposes. I'm guessing, execute some test, delete data, replay test...

When using second-level caching or query cache, the cache will and up being stale if you directly remove the data from the database.
This might result in unexpected test results.

So yes, this will conflict with Hibernate if you use second-level / query caching as the entity's will not get evicted from cache. Make sure all caches get cleared after you directly deleted any data. [See this question on how to clear cache.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302097/clear-hibernate-2nd-level-cache-after-manually-db-update)

The official Hibernate [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching) also mention this:

> Be aware that caches are not aware of changes made to the persistent store by other applications. They can, however, be configured to regularly expire cached data.

Answer (score 1):

From my experiments, since I have struggled with this for a couple hours, using `updatable = false` in the @JoinColumn will prevent Hibernate from doing

```
update theTable set theReference = null where theIdentifier = ?
```

For example (in Kotlin):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
class Course(
    @Column(name = "title")
    var title: String? = null,
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST])
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", updatable = false)
    val reviews: MutableList<Review> = mutableListOf()
) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Int? = null

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few days back I was looking for solutions here about deleting child rows on deleting parent row(Casacading Deletes), I seem to have solved it on a project am currently working on. I use Casade.ALL for my bidirectional many-to-one relationship.
Solution:

```
// Parent Entity.
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<RequisitionDetail> children = new LinkedList<>();
    ...
    // Getters & Setters.
    ...
}

// Child Entity.
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
    ...
    // Getters & Setters.
    ...
}

// Save your entities as below.
public void requisitionInsert() {
    try {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child child = new Child();
        List<Child> children = new LinkedList<>();
        ...
        // Add parent to child
        child.setParent(parent);
        // Add child to list
        children.add(child);
        // Add children list to parent 
        parent.setChilds(children);
        // Save parent entity
        ParentDao.saveParent(parent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

My cascading deletes failed at first since my parent rows had no child rows and doing it this way sloved my errors and cascading deletes work fine too.