# Truncate Table command from Sql Developer tool on Oracle 12C Database do not remove data from table

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, truncate

I have recently installed `oracle server 12c` and deployed `Java Spring-Hibernate` application.

While I am doing a `TRUNCATE` commands from `SqlDeveloper` tool and sending `commit` command, the data is not reflected in Java application.

Only after a restart of the application, the data updated from `SqlDeveloper` is reflected. One solution suggested was to turn on the Auto Commit by using `SQL> SET AUTOCOMMIT ON;`, which I have done. But the issue persists.

Important to note, only `TUNCATE TABLE` command is not reflected, i.e. java application still finds data in the table which `TRUNCATE'`ed from SQLDeveloper, `Insert/Update commands` are getting reflected.

I am sending commit command both ways, by using Commit button from `SqlDeveloper` menu and by using `commit;` on SQL worksheet.

The same Java application (Without any changes in Configuration) is identifying the empty table (`TRUNCATE`'ed from SqlDeveloper) on another instance of Oracle 12C Server.

So, I suspect the issue is with the oracle server configuration.

Comment: If the fix is to restart *your* Java application, why do you believe that SqlDeveloper is the culprit? It is far more likely that it is your Java application that is flawed, e.g. forgetting to call `commit()` or `rollback()`, and is stuck on some earlier snapshot.

Comment: @Andreas , I do not think so, Same application code works well with other database (I do not won that server, but I can connect), SQLDeveloper commits also gets reflected on that Database server.

Comment: *"works well with other database"* Do you mean another Oracle Database instance, or some other non-Oracle database? Because Oracle is fairly unique in having Read-Committed transactions using a snapshot taken at the start of the transaction. None of the other vendors do that, at least not by default. So non-Oracle database will show new data, even in an on-going transaction.

Comment: Another Oracle 12C Databse  Instance

Comment: @Andreas Question statement updated, only TRUNCATE statement used from SqlDeveloper  is not reflected to Java application, Java application still finds Data in the TRUNCATE'ed table.

Comment: Do you use any cache in your application?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No cache, just Hibernate

Comment: Hibernate has a cache too.how do you read the data with Hibernate?

Comment: there must be a cache, use sqldeveloper to create a 2nd connection to the same data to see if your transactions have been committed - or use SQLcl or SQLPlus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear Hibernate 2nd level cache after manually DB update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40302097/5221149)