# Update of Date fields from Parent class not working in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA and wanted to update the `LastUpdatedDate` and `LastModifiedBy` fields in JPA update statement. Assume Employee is my entity class which extends `AbstractBaseEntity` class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Data
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity {

    @CreatedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "CRTE_USER_ID")
    protected String createdByUser = "TEST_USER";

    @CreatedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "CRTE_DT", updatable = false)
    protected Date createdDate = new Date();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "UPDT_USER_ID")
    protected String lastUpdatedByUser = "TEST_USER";

    @LastModifiedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "UPDT_DT")
    protected Date lastUpdatedOn = new Date();

    @Version
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "VER_NUM")
    protected Integer versionNumber = 1;
}
```

Another class

```
public class Employee extends AbstractBaseEntity{
   ...
   ...
   ...    
}
```

Below query not updating any date. How can we fix it?

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE Employee p SET p.status =:status, p.lastUpdatedOn = :lastUpdatedOn WHERE p.srcProjectKeyId = (:id)")
int updatestatus(@Param("status") String status, @Param("id") Long id, @Param("lastUpdatedOn") Date lastUpdatedOn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to [make auditing work at all](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#jpa.auditing.configuration), please insure `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation added to `@Configuration` class.

The `AuditingEntityListener` methods are called in the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` phase. AFAIK is works only if you directly manipulate entities. It doesn't work if you use `@Query` statements.

Update statement must do it manually, for example:

```
UPDATE Employee p SET p.status =:status, p.lastUpdatedOn = 
:lastUpdatedOn, p.lastUpdatedBy = :lastUpdatedBy WHERE 
p.srcProjectKeyId = (:id)
```

To get the current date use:

```
Date now = new Date();
// or
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

To get the current user (a.k.a. principal) use:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
```

Here are longer discussions about cache invalidation issues:

[Spring Boot Data JPA - Modifying update query - Refresh persistence context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258857/spring-boot-data-jpa-modifying-update-query-refresh-persistence-context)

[Spring Data JPA Update @Query not updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121620/spring-data-jpa-update-query-not-updating)

[Clear Hibernate 2nd level cache after manually DB update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302097/clear-hibernate-2nd-level-cache-after-manually-db-update)

Comment: A see you problem. "clearAutomatically = true" should actually do the job. Is it possible, you have a second level cache or some concurrency issue? How do you check, that the date is not updating???

Comment: Can you pls guide me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69512728/caused-by-java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-ora-00904-invalid-identifier?